In .vscorde-server dir(in WSL2), showing error in package.json: activationEvents and Problems loading reference https://json.schemastore.org/package
In the .vscode-server dir in WSL2, it's showing 2 problems
activationEvents: '*'
Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/package'
Earlier this problem wasn't there, but ig I deleted some node modules which were not required and one of those I remember was: eslint-imoprt-resolve. Is this issue because of this npm package?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
